# Function with auto return type as parameter

Tags: c++

This is not allowed because it contains `auto`:

```
void f(auto fp())
{
}
// error: 'auto' not allowed in function prototype
```

We can explicitly make it a function pointer and get the same error:

```
void f(auto (*fp))
{
}
```

Now if we give it a trailing return type:

```
void f(auto fp() -> int)
{
}
```

It's OK now. Is this legal, a compiler bug or an oversight?

Interestingly it doesn't allow me to make a `auto` function pointer as a parameter.

```
// OK
void f(auto f(auto () -> int) -> int)
{
}

// Complain
void f(auto f(auto (*fp) -> int) -> int)
{
}
```

Comment: `auto (*fp)` is a plain pointer, a function pointer looks like `auto (*fp)()`.

Comment: It looks like an omission to me, because gnu compiler chokes on this ([demo](http://ideone.com/BCEv7U)).

Comment: This question was caused by a problem **that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [MCVE].

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Please don't use ideone. It's full of advertisements, [their links rot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284375/6292850) and they have an old version of GCC (5.1, even though most people are using 5.3.1 or 6.1 now).

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Please use adblock, it strips advertisements off ideone so nicely that the first time that I became aware of their page having too many advertisements is when I read your comment. I usually see one very modest ad in the right corner leading to a very nice online judge for programming competition training.

Answer (score 4):

`auto` as used for automatic type deduction is different from `auto` used to specify a trailing return type.

`auto` for automatic type deduction is not supported for function arguments in C++11.

However, C++14 and later support `auto` for lambda function arguments. Essentially this creates a templated `operator()` in the lambda type.

---

Your example

```
void f( auto fp() -> int )
{}
```

uses trailing return type syntax to specify the C++03 syntax function

```
void f( int fp() )
{}
```

which due to *decay* of the function type used as formal argument type, is equivalent to

```
void f( int (*fp)() )
{}
```

with a function pointer argument.